# Jquery Validation resetForm() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Ok I have a form that has Yes and No radio buttons. When the user clicks either, it fires a radioChanged() function which checks to see which box is checked. If no is checked, it shows email fields and validates the form based on the rules. If the user clicks back on "Yes" i need the validations to reset and clear but it doesn't appear to be working. Should I just do a new validation if yes is checked that does not require the email fields?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var validator = $("#newClient");

    function radioChange() {
        if (document.getElementById("yesbutton").checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("emailSpan").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("cemailSpan").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("emailError").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("cemailError").style.display = "none";
            validator.resetForm();
        } else if (document.getElementById("nobutton").checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("emailSpan").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("cemailSpan").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("emailError").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("cemailError").style.display = "block";

            validator.validate({
                rules: {
                    Email: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 4,
                        maxlength: 48,
                        email: true
                    },
                    ConfirmEmail: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 4,
                        maxlength: 48,
                        email: true,
                        equalTo: "#Email"
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    Email: {
                        required: "Please enter a valid email address",
                        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                        maxlength: "Max length is 48"
                    },
                    ConfirmEmail: {
                        required: "Please enter a valid email address",
                        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                        maxlength: "Max length is 48",
                        equalTo: "Emails do not match"
                    }
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    if (element.attr("name") == "ConfirmEmail") error.appendTo("#cemailError");
                    else if (element.attr("name") == "Email") error.appendTo("#emailError");
                }
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I think you are missing semicolon at line 49 character 15, please check it, and use `===` to compare it compares faster and in a secure way. And please use `if (//*Condition*//) {//*Do something in curly brackets!*//}` this let's the browser to calculate `if/else` in a better way.

Comment: Well that didn't work, but I found my answer here and it works perfectly!http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression

Comment: Yeah I know but I was just providing you some tips to make your code look fine not messy.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Jacob,** it seems that you need to know some basics for creating a well based and tidy java script codes. I think the problem with your code is that you are making some small problems which are sometimes unable to be seen. Here is a updated code, tell me if this works or not.

```
var validator = $("#newClient");

function radioChange() {
    if (document.getElementById("yesbutton").checked === true) {
        document.getElementById("emailSpan").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("cemailSpan").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("emailError").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("cemailError").style.display = "none";
        validator.resetForm();
    } else if (document.getElementById("nobutton").checked === true) {
        document.getElementById("emailSpan").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("cemailSpan").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("emailError").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("cemailError").style.display = "block";

        validator.validate({
            rules: {
                Email: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4,
                    maxlength: 48,
                    email: true
                },
                ConfirmEmail: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4,
                    maxlength: 48,
                    email: true,
                    equalTo: "#Email"
                }
            },
            messages: {
                Email: {
                    required: "Please enter a valid email address",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                    maxlength: "Max length is 48"
                },
                ConfirmEmail: {
                    required: "Please enter a valid email address",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                    maxlength: "Max length is 48",
                    equalTo: "Emails do not match"
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (element.attr("name") === "ConfirmEmail") {
                    error.appendTo("#cemailError");
                }
                else if (element.attr("name") === "Email") {
                    error.appendTo("#emailError");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Hope This Helps!**

Comment: It might help more if you pointed out the changes you made and why.

Answer (score -1):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="dentistJquery.aspx.cs" Inherits="dentistJquery" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Jquery Validation with Regular Expressions.</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $.validator.addMethod("email", function(value, element) 
    {  
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,5}$/i.test(value);  
    }, 

    "Please enter a valid email address.");
//     if(document.getElementById("email").value !=null)
//     {

//     document.getElementById("contactnumber").style.display='block';
//     }

     $.validator.addMethod("firstname",function(value,element){
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{5,16}$/i.test(value);  
    },"First name is required and must be valid.");

     $.validator.addMethod("lastname", function(value,element)
     {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{5,16}$/i.test(value);  
    }, "Last Name is required and must be valid.");


    $.validator.addMethod("contactnumber",function(value,element){
    return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9\-\+]+$/i.test(value);  
    },"Contact Number is required and must be valid.");

    $.validator.addMethod("comment" ,function(value,element){
    return this.optional(element) ||  /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{10,16}$/i.test(value); 
    }, "please Enter the comment at least 50 character");

        // Validate signup form
        $("#signup").validate({
                rules: {
                        email: "required email",
                        firstname: "required firstname",
                        contactnumber: "required contactnumber",
                        lastname: "required lastname",
                        comment: "required comment",
                },


        });

    });

</script>

<style>
*{ margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
body
{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;

}
input
{
width:220px;
height:25px;
font-size:13px;
margin-bottom:10px;
border:solid 1px #333333;

}
label.error 
{

font-size:11px;
background-color:#cc0000;
color:#FFFFFF;
padding:3px;
margin-left:5px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
}


</style>

</head>

<body>

<div align="center">



<div style="width:650px; margin-top:20px" align="left">
<div style="margin-left:10px">
<form method="post" action="About.aspx" name="signup" id="signup">
<b>First Name</b><br />
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="Please Enter First Name" id="firstname" /><br />
<b>Last Name</b><br />
<input type="text" name="lastname" value=" Please Enter Last Name" id="lastname" /><br />

<b>Email</b><br />
<input type="text" name="email" value="Please Enter your Email "  id="email"  /><br />
<b>phone Number</b><br />
<input type="text" name="contactnumber" value=" Please Enter Your Contact Number"  id="contactnumber" /><br />
<b>Message</b><br />
<textarea name="comment" id="comment"   ></textarea> <br /><br />
<input type="submit" value=" Submit " name='SUBMIT' id="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please learn to use the code button to indent code.  It is the `{}` symbol above the edit text box.  You highlight your code and press the button, and it is indented as code, which is much easier to read.